# Unsupported operation: Android, Retrofit, OkHttp. Adding interceptor in OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I am trying to add token based authentication via Retrofit 2.0-beta3 and OkHttpClient in Android using interceptors. But I get   UnsupportedOperationException when I add my interceptor in OkHttpClient.
Here is my code:
In ApiClient.java

```
public static TrequantApiInterface getClient(final String token) {
        if( sTreqantApiInterface == null) {

            Log.v(RETROFIT_LOG, "Creating api client for the first time");
            OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

            okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", token)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

            Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            sTreqantApiInterface = client.create(TrequantApiInterface.class);
        }
        return sTreqantApiInterface;
    }
```

And I use it like:

```
private void ampFreqTest(){
    String token = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .getString(getString(R.string.key_token), "");

    service = ApiClient.getClient(token);
    //I get an exception on this line:
    Call<List<AmpFreq>> call = service.getUserAmpFreq("1");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AmpFreq>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<AmpFreq>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "Got result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            Log.v(ApiClient.RETROFIT_LOG, "Success api client." + response.message());
            Log.v(ApiClient.RETROFIT_LOG, "Success api client.");
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.v(ApiClient.RETROFIT_LOG, "Fail api client." + t.getMessage() );
        }
    });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Process: com.trequant.usman.trequant_android, PID: 14400
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:932)
 at com.trequant.usman.trequant_android.api.ApiClient.getClient(ApiClient.java:41)
```

It gives me error on adding a new interceptor saying that it is not modifiableCollection but the documentation for interceptors() function says: /**

```
   * Returns a modifiable list of interceptors that observe the full span of each call: from before
   * the connection is established (if any) until after the response source is selected (either the
   * origin server, cache, or both).
   */
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a bug?

Comment: which version of OkHttp are you using ?

Comment: @Usmankhan Did you try my solution?

Comment: Sorry I didn't update it before but yeah, I had changed my code to what you'd suggested. And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This issue occurs when you change  **Retrofit 2.0-beta2** to  **Retrofit 2.0-beta3**. You have to use builder if you want to create `OkHttpClient` object.

Change :

```
 OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

 okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
       @Override
       public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", token)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
 });
```

to :

```
 OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .addInterceptor(
               new Interceptor() {
                 @Override
                 public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                       Request original = chain.request();

                       // Request customization: add request headers
                       Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                               .header("Authorization", token)
                               .method(original.method(), original.body());

                       Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                       return chain.proceed(request);
                   }
               })
           .build();
```

It should resolve your problem.

Comment: are they using okhttp3 by default ?

Comment: Do you mean Retrofit 2.0-beta3 ? If yes - the answer is yes. As far I know there is no more `com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient` in beta3. I had the same issue yesterday ;)

Comment: if there is no `OkHttpClient` how do you instantiate it ?

Comment: `com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient` is replaced by `okhttp3.OkHttpClient`

Comment: As I wrote above ;) *Do you mean Retrofit 2.0-beta3 ? If yes - the answer is yes*

Comment: I mean *in* `Retrofit 2.0-beta3`, which was the topic of the question

Comment: ok ;)  I wanted to be more clear but I made my answer less clear. sorry

Comment: I guess. Btw nice catch

Comment: It does resolve my problem, but I just want to ask if the api is broken?
Because the documentation for the function .interceptor() says that it returns a modifiable List. Which clearly doesn't happen.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak has the okHttp3 package actually changed? Because I am using "com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient" in gradle and OkHttp main page says the same thing

Comment: @Usmankhan Use these dependencies:
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta3'

Comment: Not working using eclipse got an exception after `OkHttpClient.Builder().build();`

Comment: where u define token]

Comment: Do you mean auth token?? You can add new Interceptor  and in intercept method you can add header or you can pass header as first args of your client method, but the better way is using interceptor

Answer (score 5):

Try this if the other answer doesn't work:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor())
    .build();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://google.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add In this way also.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("ENDPOINT_URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(client)
            .build();
```